# Time in string to time.Time

Tags: go

I have a time string in the format of `07:00:00 Australia/Melbourne` and I want to convert it to respective `America/New_York` time. I have tried below code:

```
func parseLocation(timeStr string, location string) {
    loc, err := time.LoadLocation(location)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    var parsedTime time.Time
    hour, err := strconv.Atoi(timeStr[:2])
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error converting to int %v", err)
    }
    if hour >= 10 {
        parsedTime, err = time.ParseInLocation("15:04:05", timeStr, loc)
    } else {
        parsedTime, err = time.ParseInLocation("03:04:05", timeStr, loc)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error parsing %v", err)
    }
    americaLocation, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
    resultTime := parsedTime.In(americaLocation)
    return resultTime
}

func main(){
    x := strings.Split("07:00:00 Australia/Melbourne", " ")
    parseLocation(x[0], x[1])
}
```

Converting hh:mm:ss in time.Time gives me `0000-01-01 07:00:00 +0000 UTC` which I need to convert it to other timezone which ends up giving vague output.

I want to parse the time format in the form `"07:00:00"` in time.Time format. Any suggestion for doing it in better way will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because of daylight saving time, the difference in local times varies. Therefore, without a date, there is no answer to your question.

Comment: An example of the difference in local times because of differences in daylight saving time transition dates: https://play.golang.org/p/FmaWx7pzNIi

Answer (score 2):

With this time arithmetic, you are getting into negative time values. It looks like the results are not well-defined for negative times. If you take the current date as the baseline, things seem to work. After parsing the time:

```
now:=time.Now()
parsedTime=time.Date(now.Year(),now.Month(),now.Day(),parsedTime.Hour(),parsedTime.Minute(),parsedTime.Second(),parsedTime.Nanosecond(),loc)
americaLocation, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")
resultTime := parsedTime.In(americaLocation)
```

Comment: Its possible to convert time.Now to the desired location. But when you have time hh:mm:ss in string and converting that to time.Time and then parsing in the desired location is difficult. Thats what I am looking for

Comment: time.Now().In(location) should work. I don't understand the rest of the question, is that not what you describe above already?

Comment: I don't want to convert time.Now() which is possible according to the answer provided, but I want to convert time in `07:00:00 Australia/Melbourne` format. Edited the question. I hope it's clear

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to parse/format location information. What you did already is the simplest way I know. Time format works with offsets or time zones, not locations.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: For the difference in local times, which varies, your answer makes no sense.

Comment: @peterSO the solution gives the differences as of local now, doesn't it?

Comment: @BurakSerdar: As you said: "things **seem** to work." The worst kind of bug. When is it useful to know the answer for the date a millisecond or so before the calculation was performed? When is it not useful? What are the consequnces if it's wrong? Details matter.

Comment: @peterSO, the solution uses local times for two different locations. If you take the current date in one of those locations, add the given time, and get the time in the second location, the difference is valid, is it not? `Time.In(loc)` looks the the DST for the locations.

Comment: There is a problem that occurs around transition times. The time "01:23:45" occurs twice in two different hours in time zone "America/New_York" on one particular fall day (eg Nov 3 2019) (and no times at all in one one-day period in spring). Given that time string, and the string "America/New_York", you cannot tell whether the 1-AM was the one that was in EST, or the subsequent one an hour later in EDT. If you don't mind this ambiguity, the remainder of the problem is solvable.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: No. As I said, the difference can and does vary. The daylight saving time transition (start, end) dates don't match in this case and others. [Daylight saving time by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country). The synchronized and unsynchronized time difference are not the same.

Comment: @BurakSerdar: An example: When it  is 07 in Melbourne, is it 15 or 16 in New York? https://play.golang.org/p/FmaWx7pzNIi

Comment: @torek: "the remainder of the problem is solvable." See my comments.

Comment: @peterSO Right, it's solveable except for the ambiguity. If you have a time zone database (which Go does, it has the Olson DB), you can tell, given the location, day of year, and time of day, whether some DST shift is in effect and if so, how big the DST shift is ... *except* for certain ambiguous hours that occur twice. The transition times and their shifts are all findable from the data in the Olson DB. Actually *solving* this is kind of a pain and pointless if you're willing to put up with huge amounts of time-slop, and since you *can't* solve it for the ambiguous times... *shrug*

Comment: The *right* way to do this is to have the time stamps themselves in universal time in the first place and/or to have them record whether some DST shift is in effect locally. That removes the ambiguity, hence the need for huge amounts of time-slop, and also removes the need to grub through the DB to see if the supplied time was ambiguous in the first place.